# Is it possible to assign a sign to "Todo" group?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, signs

Is it possible to add a sign to be displayed in the signs column whenever the line has a ToDo group (ToDo,FIXME...).

Tweaking my colorscheme I changed the highlight of the Todo group, but would like to have an indicator in the signs column, like Syntastic errors and warnings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this function :

```
function! SignKeyword()

    silent! sign undefine todo

    sign define todo text=>> texthl=Search

    g/\v\C(<TODO>|<FIXME>)/execute "sign place 9999 line=" . line('.')
    \ . " name=todo buffer=" . bufnr('')

    nohlsearch

endfunction
```

Now call the function on the command line :

```
:call SignKeyword()
```

Or add a mapping in your `~/.vimrc` to call it :

```
nnoremap <your mapping> :call SignKeyword()<cr>
```

Or add an autocmd. For example if you want the function to be called automatically when opening a file whose filetype is markdown  :

```
autocmd FileType markdown call SignKeyword()
```

---

The first line of the function `silent! sign undefine todo` deletes the sign todo if it already exists, so that if your signs are misplaced after deleting or adding a line, you can recall the function to fix them immediately.

---

The second line defines a sign whose name is todo, whose text is `>>` (you can change it to suit your preferences) and which uses the Search highlighting group (same thing).

---

The third line uses the global command :

```
:g/pattern/command
```

The global command executes a command on every line that matches a pattern.

Here the pattern is `\v\C(<TODO>|<FIXME>)`, which means any line containing either the word **TODO** or **FIXME**.
The regex includes the atom `\C` so that the search respects the case (no matter what your 'ignorecase' option is). If you want the search to not respect the case, change it to `\c`.

Whenever such a line is found the following line is executed by the function :

```
execute "sign place 9999 line=" . line('.')
    \ . " name=todo buffer=" . bufnr('')
```

It executes (with the `:execute` command) the content of the following string :

```
"sign place 9999 line=" . line('.') . " name=todo buffer=" . bufnr('')
```

The string includes two vim built-in functions : `line()` and `bufnr()`.
`line('.')` returns the number of the current line when a match is found by the global command, and `bufnr('.')` returns the number of the current buffer.

So for example, if the global command finds a match on line 10 in the buffer  5, it will give :

```
"sign place 9999 line=" . 10 . " name=todo buffer=" . 5
```

The dots concatenate the strings, and so it will finally evaluate to :

```
"sign place 9999 line=10 name=todo buffer=5"
```

Which is the `:sign` command placing a sign on line 10 in buffer 5.
9999 is a random id chosen for the sign (you can choose another one).

---

The fourth line of the function `:nohlsearch` disables the highlighting of the matched patterns.

Edit : I fixed the regex, the original was wrong.
I wrote `^[TODO|FIXME]` but instead I think it should be `\v\C(<TODO>|<FIXME>)`.
Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm still learning vimscript.

Comment: how to remove the sign once the `TODO` comment has been removed?

Comment: To delete the sign, you can use this command :    `sign undefine todo`

Comment: that's not what I expected, because that remove all the `todo` signs, but however just noticed that removing the line the sign is removed, so that's ok

Comment: Ok, I've added this line at the beginning of the function : `silent! sign undefine todo`. It deletes the sign todo if it already exists, so that if your signs are misplaced after deleting a line containing the keyword TODO or FIXME, you can recall the function to fix them immediately.

Comment: The regex was wrong, I typed `^[TODO|FIXME]` but instead it should have been `\v(TODO|FIXME)`. The new regex will match a line containing one of the keywords but not the beginning of the line, since I suppose a line could contain some code before a comment for example like this `some code # FIXME this line needs to be fixed`. The previous regex was completely wrong, sorry for the inconvenience, I'm still learning vimscript...

Comment: The problem with this approach is, it will get quikly out of sync, if you modify the buffer, e.g. add another line above a TODO line.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Your plugin is probably much better because it's dynamic, that's why I upvoted your answer. Besides my function should not `undefine` but `unplace` because the help says "If signs with this {name} are still placed this will cause trouble.". Unfortunately, when I tried to use `unplace` in the function, it didn't work. Anyway, that was just my attempt at solving the problem on my own.

Answer (score 6):

You can use my [DynamicSigns](https://github.com/chrisbra/DynamicSigns) plugin. This allows for so called "SignExpression" which are similar to the fold expression.

So you can simply do `:SignExpression getline(v:lnum)=~'TODO'?'Warning':0`

Read the help for more exmples of what is possible.

The advantage of using my plugin is, that it tracks changes of the buffer and adjusts the signs accordingly.